# How to replace two characters in a String with replace/regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to modify two characters in the string, for example change each `'i'` into `'e'`, and each `'e'` into `'i'` so text like `"This is a test"` will become `"Thes es a tist"`.

I've made a solution that works, but it is boring and inelegant:

```
String input = "This is a test";
char a = 'i';
char b = 'e';

char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if(chars[i] == a) {
        chars[i] = b;
    }else if(chars[i] == b) {
        chars[i] = a;
    }
}

input = new String(chars);
```

How can this be accomplished with regex?

Comment: @feelingunwelcome that duplicate is about swapping *two* characters (changing their positions), while this is about *changing* characters with different ones while *replacement* characters doesn't even need to exist in original string at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java 9 we can use [`Matcher#replaceAll(Function<MatchResult,String>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-). So you can create regex which will search for either `i` or `e`, and when it finds it let function pick replacement based on found value (like from map)

Demo

```
Map<String, String> replacements = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry("i", "e"), 
        Map.entry("e", "i")
);
String replaced = Pattern.compile("[ie]")
                         .matcher(yourString)
                         .replaceAll((match) -> replacements.get(match.group()));
```

But to be honest your solution doesn't look bad, especially if it is used for searching for single characters.

Comment: That's a really cool solution, but I'm on Java 8, unfortunately.

Comment: I would like to remind that Java 11 will be released in this month. Anyway using map to pick replacement can be also applied in your own solution instead of `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

A less elegant solution than Pschemo's but usable since Java 8:

```
static String swap(String source, String a, String b) {
    // TODO null/empty checks and length checks on a/b
    return Arrays
        // streams single characters as strings
        .stream(source.split(""))
        // maps characters to their replacement if applicable
        .map(s -> {
            if (s.equals(a)) {
                return b;
            }
            else if (s.equals(b)) {
                return a;
            }
            else {
                return s;
            }
        })
        // rejoins as single string
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Invoked on `"This is a test"`, it returns:

```
Thes es a tist
```

**Note**

As mentioned by others, your solution is fine as is for single characters.

Comment: We can also use instead of `if`s `Map<String, String> replacements` and `map(s->replacements.getOrDefault(s,s))` to let `s` be returned in case when `replacement` doesn't have `s` key.